# GoogleSheets: Screen a Column for IDs and return associated cells (multiple occurrences)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, data-extraction

Essentially I have a data-structure like this (hundreds of rows, constantly updated):

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | date1 | value 1 |
| 1001 | date2 | value 2 |
| 1002 | date3 | value 3 |
| 1001 | date4 | value 4 |
| 1003 | date5 | value 5 |

where

- IDs are unique but can occur multiple times
- Dates indicate when IDs were created or their values updated
- Values are not unique

What I want to do is to search the ID row and get the date&value associated with it. IF the same ID occurs again, it should be listed in the same row, e.g.

| ID | Date | Value |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | date1 | value 1 |  |  |
| 1001 | date2 | value 2 | date 4 | value 4 |
| 1002 | date3 | value 3 |  |  |
| 1003 | date5 | value 5 |  |  |

Ideally, this is done using an array. Like I said, the list is constantly updated so dragging a formula like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$2:$A, $B$2:$B = A2))
```

isn't really an option...

Any thoughts? Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), {A2:A&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))-1, B2:C}, {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(A2:A="",,{A2:A&"×", TO_TEXT(B2:B)&"×"&C2:C&"¤×", ROW(A2:A)&TO_TEXT(B2:B)&"×"&C2:C&"¤×"}), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), "×")), "¤", ))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16RYl0nSYakAdENxdVXI5MKxWs_qAmNsOdBBqkLVR9ZA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Yes and no - unfortunately. Maybe I don't make myself terribly clear:
The idea is that ALL values of a given ID are listed side-by-side. In your example for 1003: date5 value 5 date 6 value 6 date 7 value 7

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with sample of real date and values?

Comment: sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tr82TKGFXfu8z_UYfV7pri2bmH8BMkH3Ax4r8-QEvpU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: like I said, the idea is that the status gets updated from time to time. each update gets a new row, so I need to "collect"/"condense" all data for one ID for subsequent analysis